# Where should I choose to subscribe the HttpClient in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have tried to create a simple Angular application. I need basic CRUD functions with a database in the backend. For the http actions I am using a service.

There are some functions like

```
 ...
 getPublicEvent(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<Event[]>(this.publicEventUrl)
  }

 setEvent(Event) {
   return this.http.post(this.editEventUrl, Event)
  }
 ...
```

The other component "create" subscribes to the service and executes the HTTP request.

I have seen some tutorials where the subscribe is done directly in the service file. What is good now? Both works. 
What about error handling and error output? 
How do I proceed for a good structure??

Comment: No, both don't work. If you subscribe in the service, you can't return anything meaningful anymore to the component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that both variants provide the desired data. You are probably right that no other things are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both subscribing at the service and at the component level is valid, but one is more flexible than the other.

If you choose to subscribe at the service level you lose the flexibility of choosing what it does at the component level. However, at some point you might want to do that to lock down the functionality of the service's method, that is usually rare. Most of the time people will opt to subscribe at the component level; it makes the service method more extensible.

As far as error handling, this is declared after the initial callback function (if applicable) when subscribing. 
Example:

```
getPublicEvent().subscribe(
  () => console.log('do something...'), // initial callback (optional)
  error => console.log(error),          // error callback (optional)
  () => console.log('complete')         // subscribe complete callback (optional)
)
```

You can read more about Observables and subscribing at the RxJS documentation [here](https://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe)

Answer (score 1):

If you subscribe at the component level, you can chain your HTTP requests differently per component. I'm assuming components will need different data and sometimes you need dependent data to load in a chain or in async groups(forkjoins).

Also it should be the concern of the component of **WHEN** it will need to consume the API not the services.

Thus I would recommend you subscribe at the component level.